# unable to symbolicate crash log from a MonoTouch program

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a MonoTouch app that I built in debug and uploaded to the device. I ran the app in the debugger and the app died without the debugger catching anything. I have a .crash log for it. I ran:

symbolicatecrash myapp.crash myapp.dSYM

It got symbol information for Apple stuff like CFRunLoopRunInMode and UIApplication, but not for anything in my program.

Is there a different way I need to symbolicate MonoTouch crash logs?

Comment: Is the dSYM file from the exact same build?  All my builds symbolicate just fine in Xcode organizer here.

Comment: You can also check the iPhone Console in Xcode or iPhone Configuration Utility for a managed stacktrace.

Comment: Yeah, it was the exact same build. Next time, I'll try the iPhone Console and Configuration Utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this same problem and we created a work around...

When we ran symbolicatecrash with the -v parameter (verbose) we saw it was complaining about not having a binary file inside the dSYM package.  So we manually copied the binary file from within the app package into the dSYM package and that worked.  Something like [MyProject].app/[MyProject] to [MyProject].app.dSYM/[MyProject].

We then created this as a Custom Command to run After Build:

```
cp ${TargetDir}/${ProjectName}.app/[MyProject] ${TargetDir}/${ProjectName}.app.dSYM/${ProjectName}
```

*Note the [MyProject] portion as the binary created in the app package is a different name than the project name for us for some reason.*

Now all builds symbolicate fine from terminal and within Xcode organizer.  I hope there's a less band-aid way, but we were in a time crunch and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and posted a [patched version of symbolicatecrash](https://github.com/chrispix/symbolicatecrash-fix) to github. Replace /usr/local/bin/symbolicatecrash with this and you should be back in business.

Answer (score 0):

tholsens answer is correct but when using Xcode >=4.3 (which is installed as an application) you need to run xcode-select first:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Otherwise you'll get strange errors like 'does not contain slice armv6', etc.