# Is it possible to symbolicate MonoTouch crash dumps and get line numbers out of them?

Tags: xcode, crash, xamarin.ios, crash-dumps, symbolicate

Is it possible to symbolicate MonoTouch crash dumps and get line numbers out of them? If so, how is it done?

I have configured my project in the following way:

- Build in release mode
- Checked 'Enable debugging' in Project Options -> Build -> iPhone Build -> General tab
- Checked 'Emit debugging information' in Project Options -> Build -> Compiler

Now, when I run symbolicatecrash against a dump, I get my method names in the stack trace but with only an offset against them (eg '+ 268') rather than a line number.

I am using MonoTouch 4.21.

Comment: No it's not - but it's an Apple word (in an Apple world ;-) see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** I *think* the issue is with the ahead-of-time (AOT) compiler - but you better email such question to the [mono-devel mailing-list](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-devel-list) to get a definitive answer.

**Long answer:**

Mono compilers/runtime (and that behavior is inherited by MonoTouch) keeps the debugging information, that includes line numbers, for its assemblies inside **mdb** files.

XCode works with **DWARF** (DSYM) files. When XCode symbolicate a crash dump it looks (only) in the (AOT-produced) DWARF symbols to get its information - i.e. the **mdb** files are not looked up.

Now the Mono [debugger](http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging) (and runtime) can cope with DWARF too (which should fit the bill). However for MonoTouch I'm not sure the AOT compiler (which calls **gcc**) is producing the *final* DWARF symbols containing the C# line numbers - resulting in *symbols* and *offsets* (both available to gcc) only being available.

Comment: So you're saying it is not possible? Why did it work for Geoff? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398986/unable-to-symbolicate-crash-log-from-a-monotouch-program

Comment: *You can also check the iPhone Console in Xcode or iPhone Configuration Utility for a managed stacktrace.* <- those are separate logs (from the crash dump) and separate tools. The question is not if it was possible to **see** managed stacktraces (easy for a local crash) but if you can get them from the crash dump (like you get from a third party).

Answer (score 1):

which version of xcode are you using?

There was an problem in earlier versions - 
check https://github.com/chrispix/symbolicatecrash-fix